# How do I sort probabilities?

Tags: probability

I have question in hand in which I calculate the probability for a student to "study properly" for 15 days in first 4 weeks. Then for the same student to study properly for 21 days in the next 4 weeks and for him to study properly for 28 days in the last 4 weeks.

I know the probability of him studying properly, which is 0.8263.

Now the way I solved this was using this equation I made:

```
(1-binocdf(14,28,0.8263))*(1-binocdf(20,28,0.8263))*(1-binocdf(27,28,0.8263))
```

But here, I didnt sort them. I want to make sure he studies properly for 15 days in the first 4 week but in my equation, it could be any week. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your expression looks reasonable.  The third term is $0.8263^{28} \approx 0.00478$ so small, as you might expect if you want the student to study every day.  In reality the probabilities on each day may change as the exam approaches

Comment: I am confused by "sort" and "any week". Do you want to specify the first $4$ weeks or an arbitary week anywhere in the period ? Please clarify.

Comment: I just learnt that in probability, the things are already sorted. To simplify my question to a more normal one: Lets say we are throwing 3 dies, what is the probability of getting a 3 on first, 5 on second and 2 on the third. It is (1/6)^3. I got confused for a bit and asked "how are we sure that it is the first die that results in 3 and not the second" but I realised that this doesnt matter. Thank you people. @Peter

Comment: From what I gather here, the problem is about three different questions, and you're multiplying the answers for each of them together; may I ask why? Also, a doubt I have: the statement says 'for a student to study properly for 15 days'; does that mean 'study for exactly 15 days' or 'study for at least 15 days'?

Comment: @JoseRamirez the question is an at least question, sorry for that. And this is made of one question. The whole guestion says that in this given 12 weeks, if the student studies accordingly, they will have 3.5 gpa.

Comment: I now see, hahahaha!